# Simple Integrable function well defined everywhere in domain of integration can not be integrated on Python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numeric, sqrt

There is a function that I want to double integrate using scipy double quad.
The function is well defined everywhere in the domain and when computing the value of the function on Python I have a real finite number for each point. However when I integrate it I encounter the error 'invalid value encountered in sqrt' which is untrue as the 'dodgy' points where the square roots within the function tend towards zero are still none negative in the argument. Its driving me crazy.

Here is the code, please let me know :

```
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



beta,h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4,a_1,a_2,m,p,q=sym.symbols('beta h_1 h_2 h_3 h_4 a_1 a_2 m p q', real=True)


f_1=sym.diff((1/beta)*sym.log( (sym.sqrt(p)+4/5*sym.sqrt(50/101-p))**2*(sym.exp(beta*(m+h_1)*a_1)+sym.exp(beta*(m+h_1)*a_2))+
        +(4/5*sym.sqrt(p)+sym.sqrt(50/101-p))**2*(sym.exp(beta*(m+h_2)*a_1)+sym.exp(beta*(m+h_2)*a_2))
        +(sym.sqrt(q)+4/5*sym.sqrt(51/101-q))**2*(sym.exp(beta*(m+h_3)*a_1)+sym.exp(beta*(m+h_3)*a_2))
        +(4/5*sym.sqrt(q)+sym.sqrt(51/101-q))**2*(sym.exp(beta*(m+h_4)*a_1)+sym.exp(beta*(m+h_4)*a_2))),m).subs({beta:10,h_1:0,h_2:1.01/sym.sqrt(2),h_3:-1.01/sym.sqrt(2),h_4:0,a_1:1/sym.sqrt(2),a_2:-1/sym.sqrt(2),m:0})

print(f_1)

f=lambda p,q,: (780.080275764744*sqrt(2)*(0.8*sqrt(p) + sqrt(0.495049504950495 - p))**2 - 780.080275764744*sqrt(2)*(sqrt(q) + 0.8*sqrt(0.504950495049505 - q))**2)/(10*(156.028873819841*(0.8*sqrt(p) + sqrt(0.495049504950495 - p))**2 + 2*(sqrt(p) + 0.8*sqrt(0.495049504950495 - p))**2 + 2*(0.8*sqrt(q) + sqrt(0.504950495049505 - q))**2 + 156.028873819841*(sqrt(q) + 0.8*sqrt(0.504950495049505 - q))**2))



I=integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 50/101, 0, 51/101)

print(I)
```

I print the function and then paste it to lambdify it because when going to symbolic function to integration within scipy I get some float error.

Comment: Using `sympy` variables and expressions in `numpy/scipy` code often does not work.  `np.array([beta, h_1])` produces a object dtype array, and `np.sqrt(object_array)` will produce your first error.  `float(beta)` will produce the float error.  A proper use of `sympy.lambdify` often gets around these issues, though it isn't perfect.  It's better to use `sympy's` own integration functions where possible.

Comment: When asking about errors, you should post them in full.  Otherwise we have to run your code (is the copy-n-paste complete?), and generate them ourselves.  Working just from reading the code, and past experiences, often isn't enough (or too much work :) ).

Comment: You have your limits the wrong way around. Try `integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 51/101, 0, 50/101)` instead of `integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 50/101, 0, 51/101)`. Note that the docs for `dblquad` refer to the integral of `func(y, x)`, and the limits are the limits for `x` (the second parameter of `func`) followed by those for `y` (the first parameter of `func`).

Comment: More: you could debug this yourself by turning `f` into a proper `def` function, inspecting the result before returning it, and dropping into a debugger (or just printing stuff) if the result is a NaN. Then you get to see the exact inputs `p` and `q` that caused the nan, and trace through the computation to find out at what point it was introduced and where your assumptions were being violated.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Got it thank you very much now I obtain a numerical result. However, it does not agree with the result I obtain when integrating the same function on MATLAB. What could be the source of this discrepancy?

Comment: @TheDawg Sorry, no idea; we'd need to see a reproducible example including the MATLAB code to be able to help with that. There are many many things that could have gone wrong in translation, and without seeing the code it's impossible to start guessing.

Comment: I'd suggest first checking that the Python version of your function and the MATLAB version agree at a selected bunch of random points in the domain.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The function agrees everywhere, on MATLAB I simply use the integral2 module with the limit of integration of different order with respect to the python integration as you mentioned in your first response. That should be it for double integration and yet I obtain different results. On MATLAB I get -0.0017, on Python I get -0.022.